# LightGBM 'class_weight' parameter: To use with Binary Classification or not?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, lightgbm

When dealing with class imbalance issue, penalizing the majority class is a common practice that I have come across while building Machine Learning models. Hence, I often use class weights post re-sampling. LightGBM is one efficient decision tree based framework that is believed to handle class imbalance well. So I am using a LightGBM model for my binary classification problem. The dataset has high class imbalance in the ratio 34:1.

I initially used the LightGBM Classifier with 'class weights' parameter. However, the documentation of LightGBM Classifier mentions to use this parameter for multi-class problems only. For binary classification, it suggests using the 'is_unbalance' or 'scale_pos_weight' parameters. But, by using class weights I see better results and it is also easier to tune the weights and track performance of the model in comparison to when using the other two params.

But since the documentation recommends not to use it for Binary Classification, are there any repercussions of using the parameter? I am getting good results with it on my test data and validation data, but I wonder if it will behave otherwise on other real time data?

Comment: Perhaps asking the question on datascience stackexchange might get you a better audience? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Documentation recommends alternative parameters:

> Use this parameter only for multi-class classification task; for binary classification task you may use `is_unbalance` or `scale_pos_weight` parameters.

https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html